# Adjust padding for deleted posts in flag history

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, flag-history

It looks like some CSS changes have been pushed out recently. There's a minor blemish on the flag history page: deleted posts have a red background, which does have some padding at the beginning but not at the end:

[image: screenshot of flag history]

Also, I think it will look nicer if those titles would be aligned to the left of the table.

Comment: also on MSO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394509/todays-css-update-broke-flag-page but there reported as bug

Comment: Same on the answers/questions pages: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344858/260198

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed; the background color on deleted posts now spans the whole title in the flag history. As shown in the screenshot:

[image: screenshot of flag history]