# Incorrect highlighting deleted posts in profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, moderator-tools

On the [answers page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/15479/suvitruf-says-reinstate-monica?tab=answers) I can (probably, because I'm mod) see deleted answers. And row's highlighting is broken right now.

> [image]

Comment: probably related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344847/adjust-padding-for-deleted-posts-in-flag-history

Comment: @rene yeah, looks like this issues appeared after the last update)

Comment: Yeah, we're beta testing, except we're doing it in production ...

Comment: @rene haha_classic.jpg (:

Comment: I was just going to report this ...

Comment: Is that, perhaps, *omega testing*, @rene?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleted posts on profile page have broken formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344910/deleted-posts-on-profile-page-have-broken-formatting)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog my post was earlier)

Comment: That one has an answer.