# Deleted posts on profile page have broken formatting

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, deleted-posts

Deleted posts (shown in red) have broken formatting on the profile page:

[image: broken formatting]

The screenshot is from my profile on Arqade Meta, running the latest version of Firefox with all addons disabled.

Comment: Yeah, it's in the CSS. `.deleted-answer` class has a `margin-left: -24px` rule that cause all the content to be shifted to the left.

Comment: Related: [Warning Underflow™ in flag dialog for flag warning/ban messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344865/294055)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

This is now fixed:

[image: deleted answers now align properly]